# Laravel sanctum API token authentication fail

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel sanctum to create API tokens that can be used to authenticate API requests, but when I create a token and use the plaintext token to authenticate requests from postman always gives me 401.

here is my end point:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user();
});
```

I generate tokens like this:

```
$user = $request->user();
        $abilities = [];

        if ($request->read) $abilities[] = 'data:read';
        if ($request->write) $abilities[] = 'data:write';

        $token = $user->createToken($request->name, $abilities);

        return response([
            'token' => $token->plainTextToken,
            'tokens' => $user->tokens
        ],201);
```

I do get the palintext token back but when I use it in postman it fails

```
Bearer 118586|IgKEMCTQq85Lb6k1km6HrewBo3wUS23OuTNHj13i
```

I use this middleware in my API group

```
EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
```

and I turned it off but nothing change.

can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone facing this issue,
you have to change the api driver from `token` to `sanctum` in `config/auth.php` `guards => api => driver`

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

],
```

Comment: I honestly tried this, and the return I get in Postman is "This action is unauthorized".

I did, however, find some success by not including this and updating the Model's Request files (Store and Update in my instance) to:
`public function authorize() { return false; }`